# How to open two webpages in two different chrome-windows in fullscreen via batch-script?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, window, fullscreen

I have two monitors, two locally-stored webpages and a batch-script, which is able to open the webpages in new tabs.

What I want the script to do is to open the webpages **in different windows**, both in **fullscreen** (the F11-fullscreen :D) on **each monitor** (with the google-chrome browser). So that the first webpage is displayed in fullscreen on the first monitor and the second webpage on the second monitor in fullscreen as well.

If Batch is not able to realize that, don't hesitate to come up with another scripting language.

```
@echo off
start chrome.exe "%userprofile%\Desktop\Monitoring\slurm-general-view.html"
start chrome.exe "%userprofile%\Desktop\Monitoring\cluster-status.html"
```

I'm looking forward to receiving answers from you. Thanks and have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to tell chrome to start fullscreen, however, if you want it to open a new window, you have to pass the option --new-window, like this:

```
  start "" chrome.exe --new-window "%userprofile%\Desktop\Monitoring\slurm-general-view.html"
```

However, doing this does not allow other window related functions to work, like `--start-maximized`.